# How to calculate math formula in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SQL table structure for example:

[image: table structure]

Is there a way to calculate the final result in Result column.
The result should be

```
210,
1190,
-630
```

respectively.

I prefer non-dynamic query, so that I can use it in view/function.
Also the table may have 1000's of rows with different configurations.

This is my solution:

[image: solution]

It uses dynamic query and loop. Not a very efficient way.

Thank you

**Edit:**

Table structure:

```
select *,'result' as Result  from dbo.temp_20220721

sid val1       sign1    val2  sign2 val3      sign3 val4        Result
1   10.00000000 *   20.00000000 -   30.00000000 +   40.00000000 result
2   10.00000000 -   20.00000000 +   30.00000000 *   40.00000000 result
3   10.00000000 -   20.00000000 *   30.00000000 -   40.00000000 result
```

My solution:

```
create table dbo.#temp1(
    Result numeric(18,8),
)

declare @sql varchar(max), @id int

select top 1 @sql = CONCAT('select ',val1,sign1,val2,sign2,val3,sign3,val4),@id=sid from dbo.temp_20220721

while @@rowcount > 0
begin
    INSERT INTO dbo.#temp1 exec(@sql)
    select top 1 @sql = CONCAT('select ',val1,sign1,val2,sign2,val3,sign3,val4) ,@id=sid from dbo.temp_20220721 where sid > @id order by sid;
end;

select * from dbo.#temp1
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: How many different mathematical operations do you need to support? Just arithmetic? How do you specify precedence?

Comment: @Zhorov new question: construct the query that returns your answer ;)

Comment: If only 3 possible operations and 3 slots then only 27 permutations but that quickly gets out of control!

Comment: The above table is just an example. In my requirement i have division also with 8 values and 7 operators like [(((Curr_ID + Prem1 + Prem2) * Mult1 * Mult2 + Prem3) * Mult3) / Div1]. Where +,-,* and / may interchange

Comment: So how does the current schema support specifying operator precedence? How would you specify that the tuple`{a, +, b, *, c}` should be read as `(a + b) * c` rather than `a + (b * c)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not try all scenarios but this query can be work.

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE ([sid] int, 
val1 decimal(18,2), 
sign1  VARCHAR(2),  
val2  decimal(18,2),  
sign2  VARCHAR(2), 
val3  decimal(18,2),     
sign3  VARCHAR(2), 
val4  decimal(18,2))

INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES
(1, 10.00, '*', 20.00, '-' , 30.00, '+', 40.00) ,
(2, 10.00, '-', 20.00, '+' , 30.00, '*', 40.00) ,
(3, 10.00, '-', 20.00, '*' , 30.00, '-', 40.00) ,
(4, 10.00, '*', 20.00, '+' , 30.00, '/', 40.00) 


;WITH C1 AS (
select [sid],
            CASE WHEN sign1 IN( '*', '/') THEN 0  ELSE val1 END AS val1,
            CASE WHEN sign1 IN( '*', '/') THEN '+' ELSE sign1   END AS sign1,
            CASE WHEN sign1 = '*' THEN val1 * val2  
                 WHEN sign1 = '/' THEN val1 / val2 
                 ELSE val2 END AS val2,    
            sign2,val3, sign3, val4
        from @TempTable
)
, C2 AS (
    select [sid], val1,sign1, 
            CASE WHEN sign2 IN( '*', '/') THEN 0  ELSE val2 END AS val2,
            CASE WHEN sign2 IN( '*', '/') THEN sign1 ELSE sign2 END AS sign2,
            CASE WHEN sign2 = '*' THEN val2 * val3 
                 WHEN sign2 = '/' THEN val2 / val3 
                 ELSE val3  END AS val3,
            sign3, val4
        from C1
)
, C3 AS (
    select [sid], val1,sign1,val2, sign2,
            CASE WHEN sign3 IN( '*', '/') THEN 0  ELSE val3 END AS val3,
            CASE WHEN sign3 IN( '*', '/') THEN sign2 ELSE sign3 END AS sign3,
            CASE WHEN sign3 = '*' THEN val3 * val4
                 WHEN sign3 = '/' THEN val3 / val4 
                 ELSE val4  END AS val4
        from C2
),
 C4 AS (
    select *,
            CASE 
                WHEN sign1 = '+' THEN val1 + val2
                WHEN sign1 = '-' THEN val1 - val2
            END AS r1
        from C3
 )
 , C5 AS (
    select *,
            CASE 
                WHEN sign2 = '+' THEN r1 + val3
                WHEN sign2 = '-' THEN r1 - val3
            END AS r2
        from C4
 )
 , C6 AS (
    select *,
            CASE 
                WHEN sign3 = '+' THEN r2 + val4
                WHEN sign3 = '-' THEN r2 - val4
            END AS r3
        from C5
 )
 SELECT T.*, C6.r3 result  FROM C6
    INNER JOIN @TempTable T ON C6.sid = T.sid
```

Result:

```
sid    val1     sign1 val2    sign2 val3    sign3 val4    result
------ -------- ----- ------- ----- ------- ----- ------- ----------
1      10.00    *     20.00   -     30.00   +     40.00   210.0000
2      10.00    -     20.00   +     30.00   *     40.00   1190.0000
3      10.00    -     20.00   *     30.00   -     40.00   -630.0000
4      10.00    *     20.00   +     30.00   /     40.00   200.7500
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'Computed Column', please take a look at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Please ensure answers are stand alone i.e. will continue to make sense even if the link breaks. And please ensure its a complete answer to the question, not just a tip.

Comment: The complicated bit is dynamically evaluating the expression in the table - following bodmas rules. What definition should the computed column have?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).